# Unexpected ValueError after training Keras NN a few times

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am working on time series prediction using RNNs implemented in Keras on Google Colaboratory. I implemented the RNN as follows:

```
from tensorflow import keras
mae = keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
hidden_neurons = 50
output_neurons = 1
epoch_size = 50
batch_size = 72
# x_train has shape (500, 1, 23)
LSTM_layer = keras.layers.LSTM(hidden_neurons, input_shape = (x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]), dropout = 0.05) 
output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(1)
test_model = keras.Sequential(layers = (LSTM_layer, output_layer))
test_model.reset_states()
test_model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = mae)
test_model.summary()
history = test_model.fit(tf.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1), y_train, epochs = epoch_size, batch_size = batch_size, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), shuffle = False)
# y_train has shape (500, 1)
# x_test has shape (500, 1, 23)
# y_test has shape (500, 1)
```

I have the above code (except the import) in a single code cell. When I start a fresh runtime, the network trains fine as expected. But after executing the code cell for around 3-4 times, Colab throws the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-3ac5cc808611> in <module>
     12 test_model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = mae)
     13 test_model.summary()
---> 14 history = test_model.fit(tf.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1), y_train, epochs = epoch_size, batch_size = batch_size, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), shuffle = False) 
...
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 1, 23), found shape=(None, 23)
```

The error persists if `tf.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1))` is omitted in `test_model.fit()` while fitting the Sequential model.

I guess this has something to do with the layer inputs somehow being changed during execution. I have tried using `test_model.reset_states()` and running

```
keras.backend.clear_session()
del test_model
```

in a separate code cell, but only forcibly killing the Colab runtime seems to work:

```
import os
os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
```

What could cause the layer inputs to change midway during program run?

**EDIT**: I got the same error when I tried running the cells on Jupyter Notebook on my PC rather than on Colab.

Comment: What happens if you have that `tf.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1)` as `x_train_dims = tf.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1)` and then use `x_train_dims` throughout (i.e. have it as separate lines of code rather than inlining it into one line of code)?

Comment: @Pam Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but the error popped up after successfully running the code cell thrice.

Comment: The code in your question doesn't give the full story for x_train - where/how is it initialised? It already has a shape by line 8, so it's clearly initialised outside your code example. My one big beef with these notebooks is the "hidden" kernel state. I'm very good at initialising a variable on cell 10 of a notebook, then using it in cell 1 and then wondering why my notebook is broken when I close and re-open it. I use function definitions to get round this. Some cells define a function, others call a function (sometimes in a loop)!

Comment: @Pam Yes, x_train is outside the code example but has constant dimensions and no missing values. I should try clubbing the model definition and training in a function and see if that works.

Comment: @Pam This doesn't seem to work as well. So I've switched to training models locally on my PC until I figure out what could be going on.

Comment: I've only got one more suggestion (if you post again, it'd be better to include the x_train loading data and probably start a new question for more attention). Is there any way you have a dataset with only 1 sample in the third load? Like if you're partitioning the data into folders and you end up with one folder containing only 1 sample?

Comment: @Pam I couldn't exactly get your point - do you mean I should try training the model on a single batch? x_train is derived from a 23-column, 1000-row open-access dataset.

Comment: no, it *should* be ok (batch sizes in the model usually look ok). I mean that if you were (manually?) splitting that dataset into samples of, say, 333 rows (and using each of those maybe for stratified cross-fold validation - there's probably an easier way to code it than manually though), then after 3 runs, you'd be left with a sub-dataset that only had 1 sample in it. I don't think you're doing that, though, you'd know!

Comment: Oh, okay. No, I'm not using cross-validation as the problem I'm working on requires a fixed training set. Also, I'm not splitting the set in any way before feeding it to the DNN. There's probably something non-transparent going on in the backend/kernel.

Comment: After about a week of debugging, I found that the error arises only if I train the model after making predictions and evaluating accuracy scores such as RMSE using the predicted values. It does not throw up if I repeatedly train the model without making predictions.

Comment: @Pam I'm really sorry for missing your point - I should've well-checked if I'm reshaping the test or training sets anywhere in my code. After over two weeks of debugging, I found that by oversight, one of the variables named x_test_new was left named as x_test, and that one line led to the entire mess. I no longer face the problem now. The question may now be closed. Also, thank you for the help!